# How is proper CG maintained in ultralight pusher aircraft?

Tags: ultralight, cg

Considering pilot weight can vary 100lbs or more how do ultralight pusher airplanes maintain proper CG range?

Answer (score 3):

Usually with suitably-placed counterweights. I used to fly a two-place pusher Chickinox kot-kot that, to be flown alone, needed a lead counterweight of about 15kg fastened on the extreme nose.